# Can a X11 Display with multiple Screens have different visuals?

Tags: x11

If a window is created with transparency (RGBA) on one screen and the user moves the window to another screen. Can the other screen not support transparency?

```
XCreateWindow(display, xparent, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
                            vinfo.depth, InputOutput, vinfo.visual,
                            CWEventMask  | CWOverrideRedirect | CWBitGravity |
                            CWColormap | CWBackPixel | CWBorderPixel, &attr);
```

Show I verify the visual again if the Screen changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a good answer here:

[3.1 Visual Types](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/visual-types.html)

> For each screen of the display, there may be a list of valid visual types supported at different depths of the screen. Because default windows and visual types are defined for each screen, most simple applications need not deal with this complexity. Xlib provides macros and functions that return the default root window, the default depth of the default root window, and the default visual type.

see also: [2.2.3. Screen Information Macros](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/screen-information.html#DefaultVisualOfScreen)